# Back behavior using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have written JavaScript for back button like this and my HTML is

```
<a onclick="goBack()" href="javascript:">
```

and

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back(1);
}
```

my path is:

home-> page A -> Page B

its works fine when i try to redirect from page B to A works perfect but issue is than when i click on back button on page A than its take me to page B not on home page.

So how can I resolve this issue? how it can store history????

Comment: have you tried `window.history.back(-1);`

Comment: Where is the jQuery code? This is just plain Javascript.

Comment: no jquery anywhere in your code

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Comment: sorry i m new at here i changed jquery to javascript...  & Ashish Kumar i have tried already.

Comment: `history.go(-1);` *for back* and `history.go(1);` *for forward* works with charm. I tried it myself.

Comment: i have tried window.history.go(-1) is works for the browser not for the mobile app. back button so is any other script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put history.go(-1) its working on after proper build of app. so for if any has issue like i had so my suggestion is that please proper build your application. its working and some how its also doesn't support while you do test on browser.

Answer (score 1):

History doesn't work exactly the way you seem to think. When you navigate (or redirect) to a new page, the new page is **added** to the history, even if it already exists earlier in the history. In other words, the browser does **not** search for the new page in the history and assume you really wanted to go back there; instead, the new page gets added to the history. So:

```
ACTION               HISTORY
============================
start at home        home
navigate to A        home A
navigate to B        home A B
redirect to A        home A B A  <=== A is added to history
back                 home A B A
                            ^
```

So, the `back` puts you back on `B`, as expected.

By the way, `back` is just `back` with no parameter. You may want `history.go`. But that is not your problem.

Comment: how to resolve i have tried  history.go(-1); but its not working fine.

Comment: is there any chance if we have form on page and validate it on server side...and if fails to validate come back to same page...I assume it will enter 2 entries for same page in that case ?

Comment: You can't resolve this easily. If you redirect to `A` from `B`, then `A` gets **added** to the history, and "back" will go back to `B`. That's just the way history works. Depending on how your code is set up, possibly instead of redirecting from `B` to `A`, you could do a back there, which would take you back to `A`, from which another back would take you to `home`.

Comment: i have tried window.history.go(-1) is works for the browser not for the mobile app. back button so is any other script ?

Comment: `history.back()` is exactly equivalent to `history.go(-1)` (when the latter is supported).